# ONVIF server library for Python

Tags: library, python, server, video-surveillance

I want to write tests for IP Video Surveillance server. I'm using Python with pytest. I want an ONVIF server library that implements auto-discovery protocol so that I could write code like this:

```
from onvif import OnvifServer

camera = OnvifServer(listen='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
camera.stream(source='~/video.mp4')
```

I've googled "ONVIF server python", but didn't find anything.

How can I solve my task?